# как узнать что работает в системе x11 или wayland?

Tags: linux, c

Необходимо в программе узнать какая среда работает. Кода нет, потому что у меня нет ошибки. Я не знаю как делается это. Это надо сделать на языке си в линукс. Может быть получить `getenv` или как то по другому, типа попробывать инициализировать x11 и если не получиться, то инициализировать wayland?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536141/how-i-can-find-out-if-a-linux-system-uses-wayland-or-x11/45537237

Comment: @ExplodingKitten о спасибо. значит в XDG_SESSION храниться.

Comment: loginctl есть для этого)

Comment: @xverizex о нет! Полно вариантов, когда в XDG_SESSION пусто, а иксовые приложения работают.

Comment: @xverizex Вот вариант с проверкой DISPLAY/WAYLAND_DISPLAY кажется более рабочим.